# Selenium 2.18.0 - UnhandledAlertException upon driver initialization, how can you handle it?

Tags: exception, selenium, unhandled-exception

I did the mistaked and updated my **pom.xml** to selenium **2.18.0**
now the **UnhandledAlertException** during an operation is the new feature:

> Alert handling in Firefox and IE: Throwing UnhandledAlertException if an alert is present during an operation. The unhandled alert is also dismissed to mitigate repeat exceptions.

but if i call

```
driver = new InternetExplorerDriver();
```

it results in **Modal dialog present Exception**, because my current system needs proxy credentials, which are filled by a looping auto-it script (just in case somebody needs it):

```
Dim $arrTitle[2] = ["Authentification required", "Windows Security"]
While 1
For $sTitle In $arrTitle
    If WinExists($sTitle) Then
        WinActivate($sTitle);
        Send("{HOME}");
        Send("+{END}");
        Send("{DEL}");
        Send("user");
        Send("{TAB}");
        Send("{HOME}");
        Send("+{END}");
        Send("{DEL}");
        Send("password");
        Send("{ENTER}");
        Sleep(1000)
    EndIf
Next
Sleep(500)
WEnd
```

So how can I prevent this exception? If I simply

```
try { driver = new InternetExplorerDriver(); }
catch(UnhandledAlertException e) {}
```

i will receive a **driver=null**

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 1):

If your system needs proxy credentials you should be able to pass this through with your desired capabilities into the driver.

see http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/DesiredCapabilities#Proxy_JSON_Object on what to use.

Comment: but in my case, i might be lucky because it's a proxy request that can be dealt with, still... if this would be an alert of the website about something else, how can you launch your driver to handle the website if you already receive an exception before its initialized?